# Python lambda output

Tags: python

This is probably something trivial but I can't seem to find a decent solution and/or I'm searching for the wrong thing.

When I call this:

`validation_data = validation.map(tuple)`

I get the following output:

```
[(61.0, 3864.0), (61.0, 3889.0)]
```

I actually want the result to be Integers, so I changed the code to this instead:

```
validation_data = validation.map(lambda xs: [int(x) for x in xs])
```

But now the format of the output changes (notice it's now square brackets like an array instead of smooth brackets)

```
[[61, 3864], [61, 3889]]
```

I'm not sure what happens here. Why does the output format change? And how do I keep the original `[()]` format instead of `[[]]`?

Comment: What is `validation`?

Comment: Those are square brackets. Angular brackets would be `<>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
validation_data = validation.map(lambda xs: tuple(int(x) for x in xs))
```

This is essentially just combining the first statement in your question with the second. Either the only reason you had round brackets the first time was precisely because you used `tuple`, or the first statement was redundant.

Note that `tuple(int(x) for x in xs)` is a special feature of Python syntax. It's short for `tuple((int(x) for x in xs))`. That argument is a generator comprehension, and when a function has a single argument which is a generator comprehension you can remove the extra round brackets. `tuple([int(x) for x in xs])` would also work and would be closer to your code.

You could also do:

```
validation_data = validation.map(lambda xs: tuple(map(int, xs)))
```